# Java : Is it possible to replace map values with different ones each iteration?

Tags: java, dictionary, replaceall

Sorry, it was not clear enough.
So i'm trying to update, at each iteration, the values of my map (values).
I also want to store the last results of this map, in another map (lastIterValues), since i'm going to use it in my function calculate.

Problem: The values of the two maps (values, and lastIterValues) are not updating.

This is the code I wrote:

```
public Map<Integer, Double> getValues()
{
  return values; 
}

public Double calculate(int id, int iteration, Map<Integer, 
Double> lastIterValues)
{

    List<Integer> attacks; 
    Double sum= 0.0;

    attacks = getAttacks(id, iteration); 
    
    for (int i=0; i < attacks.size(); i++)
    {       
        sum += (1/ lastIterValues.get(attacks[i]));
    }
    
    return sum ;
}

public void resolve()
{
 int nbIter = 1;
        
 //To store the values of previous iteration
 Map<Integer, Double> lastIterValues = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(); 
        
 lastIterValues = getValues();
        
 //Iteration 0: Initialize with 1's
 for(int i=0; i < getAF().size(); i++)
 {
  getValues().put(i, 1.0);
 }
        
  lastIterValues = getValues();

  while(nbIter < 10)
 {

   final int iter = nbIter;
   final Map<Integer, Double> lastIterValues2 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(getValues());
   
   //Replace the map "values" with new values
   getValues().replaceAll((k, v) -> calculate(k, lastIterValues2));

   //Store this iteration in lastIterValues
   lastIterValues.replaceAll((k, v) -> getValues().get(k));
            
   nbIter += 1;

 }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are trying to do. Please create [complete, minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which illustrates your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for `Java 8` by overriding true value sources:

```
private Map<Integer, Double> getValues() {
    return Map.of(1, 1.0, 2, 2.0, 3, 3.0);
}

public void resolve() {
     getValues().entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                          e -> calculate(e.getValue())))
                .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key: " + k + ", val: " + v));
}

private Double calculate(Double value) {
    return value == 1.0 ? 1.1 : value;
}
```

The initial value of the map was:

```
key: 1, val: 1.0
key: 2, val: 2.0
key: 3, val: 3.0
```

The calculated value of the map would be:

```
key: 1, val: 1.1
key: 2, val: 2.0
key: 3, val: 3.0
```

good coding! ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to assign a value to function. That is not allowed in java.

`getValues().put(i,1.0);`

If you are using a getter than use a variable to store the getter name than call it using . e.g

`Object obj = new Object; obj.getValue`

Since you already have a variable you are using to store the values than use it until the end and replace the values of getValues using a setter

```
public void resolve()
    {
        int nbIter = 1;
        
        Map<Integer, Double> lastIterValues = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
        
        lastIterValues = getValues();
        

        for(int i=0; i < getAF().size(); i++)
        {
            lastIterValues.put(i, 1.0);
        }
       
        //I'm Not sure what you are trying to do here but it should be something like this
        while(nbIter < 10)
        {
        
            final int iter = nbIter;
            final Map<Integer, Double> lastIterValues2 = new HashMap<Integer, Double>(getValues());

            //You should use lastIterValues to calculate not getValues()
            lastIterValues.replaceAll((k, v) -> calculate(k, iter, lastIterValues2));
            
            //This variable isn't defined I think you meant nbIter
            Iter += 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: `getValues().put(i,1.0)` is perfectly valid. Without seeing the implementation of `getValues()` we can't say if it does what is intended, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: `Object obj = new Object; obj.getValue` on the other hand doesn't even compile.

Comment: `Object obj = new Object;` is just an example it's missing the implementation. Object could be anything like in this case a Map of <Integer, Double>.